# How to counter cache like (RoR) on Laravel 4 can it be done

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

how can i implement a counter_cache like in Ruby on Rails on a Laravel 4?
do i have to do it manually?

in Ruby i just made the `:counter_cache to true`

Comment: Can you explain the concept of a counter_cache, please? This makes helping you easier. :)

Comment: @Franz I know it's a pretty old question, but I am unable to find any other useful information except this question. Here's an [article that explains what counter cache is in Active Record](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html). I, too, wonder whether there's a built-in functionality in Laravel like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increment a single column value with

```
DB::table('yourtable')->increment('your_column');
```

Does that help?

**EDIT:** You want [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events). With those you can, for example, increment a counter column every time your model is updated.

Comment: i know this option.. but my question is if there is any way let Laravel handle it automatically.. like RoR do..

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? Something like increasing the counter on every update? You could use model events for that...